# how to get JMS payload and header Message and queue type

Tags: java, queue, weblogic, spring-integration

*here am getting Queue Body Content only,but want to get the value of payload,JMS Header value,queue type etc..
    If i change createNewEmployee(String newData) to createNewEmployee(Message newData) it throws exceptions like no method found createNewEmployee(java.lang.String)*

```
    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="inBound" destination="requestQueue" channel="msgReceiver" />

    <int:service-activator id="msgRouter" input-channel="msgReceiver"   output-channel="msgSender" ref="routeClass" method="createNewEmployee"/>

    public String createNewEmployee(String newData) {}

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
    public String createEmployee(Message message) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("from  message message :" + message);
            TextMessage textMessage=(TextMessage)message;
            String operation=textMessage.getStringProperty("requestType");
            String newData=textMessage.getText();
            System.out.println("from operation :"+operation);
            System.out.println("from createCmcContact :"+newData);
}
```

Comment: Please add some more code. Where exactly you are trying to get the header values? Its unclear from the given question.

Comment: How the JmsListener is setup.?

Comment: just edited Tags wrongly tag Spring instead of Spring-intergration

Comment: Do you have the correct `import` (`org.springframework.messaging.Message`) ? Show your complete `routeClass`.

Comment: See my answer for possible reason and solution

Comment: Thanks Gary,was waiting for you. Early was placed javax.jms.Message

Comment: Thanks For response Artem Bilan.But Still have small issue, JMS end they setting setStringProperty. in Spring-Intergration want to get that String via getStringProperty so placed javax.jms.Message so now looking for the way get the String .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need this property:

```
/**
 * Specify whether the JMS request Message's body should be extracted prior
 * to converting into a Spring Integration Message. This value is set to
 * <code>true</code> by default. To send the JMS Message itself as a
 * Spring Integration Message payload, set this to <code>false</code>.
 * @param extractRequestPayload true if the request payload should be extracted.
 */
public void setExtractRequestPayload(boolean extractRequestPayload) {
```

It is `extract-payload` XML attribute of the `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`.

But it is really just the best guess since your `createNewEmployee(Message newData)` doesn't want to accept a `Message`, then it is `javax.jms.Message` but not `org.springframework.messaging.Message`.